# How to resolve an object that references an activitiy for shares and reports

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

Considering the share activity: 'Mike shared John's post'
activitystrea.ms specs [indicate](http://activitystrea.ms/specs/json/1.0/#activity-object) that when an activity is shared, the new share activity should embed the original activity in its the `object` value.

In terms of GetStreams.io, it means that the object property has the value: `object: 'activity:1'`, which is later loaded through the enrichment process.

Since activities are getstream.io records, not foreign records, does getstream.io automatically resolve the object value or is it the developer's job to manually  manually load the activity reference through the enrichment process?

Answer (score 0):

The content of an activity sent to Stream is entirely controlled by you in this case, whether it's the original activity, or a 'share'.

If you want a user (let's call them Sam) to share a previous activity, you could set the actor to Sam's ID, the verb would be "share", and the object ID could be any identifier that your system could enrich back to the original activity.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. This means there is a slight performance problem. Enriching a share activity requires 2 sequential enrichment calls; First one loads the activity. The second enriches the activity's embedded references. It would be nice if GetStream scanned through the activities and automatically resolved activity references based on the pattern `activity:*`.

Comment: We're adding more and more enrichment to our SDKs to avoid N+1 lookups like this, where you'd be able to specify subreferences to enrich. I'll talk to another dev on the team about adding this to the Node SDK.